# bash shell function return to variable that can't explain

Tags: bash, function, shell

there is a simple bash shell fragment

```
function gettop()
{

 abc= /bin/pwd

}

funret=$(gettop)
echo $funret
```

the output of **funret** is the ouput of command */bin/pwd*:

```
/home/xxx/xxx
```

how does this happen?

according to shell standard, function return either with a *echo* or *return*,
but here non of these involved; but the result show me that **getopt**
returned */bin/pwd* and $() just run this command.

another thing is, after I delete the extra empty space after **abc=**
the output will become null;

what is going on here exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The output i.e. /home/xxx/xxx is an expected behavior because in shell the variables are assigned without space in them i.e. abc=/bin/pwd. Now since you have defined the variable using space shell tried to execute the string after the space during the function and the output /home/xxx/xxx is because of that execution as /bin/pwd is a know command to shell.

If you use the below code snippet it would throw an error.

```
function gettop()
 {
abc= testing
}
funret=$(gettop)
echo $funret
```

Error:

./tmp.sh: line 5: testing: command not found